# How to rotate text to be horizontal on Holoview with Bokeh

Tags: bokeh, holoviews

In the example in https://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/route_chord.html ,
how can I change the orientation of the arc labels to be horizontal? Bonus points for not overlapping - or an alternative using a seperate legend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the answer courtesy of @philippjfr from gitter, was:

```
# %%opts Chord [edge_color_index='SourceID' label_index='City' color_index='AirportID' width=800 height=800]
# %%opts Chord (cmap='Category20' edge_cmap='Category20')

def rotate_label(plot, element):
    text_cds = plot.handles['text_1_source']
    length = len(text_cds.data['angle'])
    text_cds.data['angle'] = [0]*length
    xs = text_cds.data['x']
    text = np.array(text_cds.data['text'])
    xs[xs<0] -= np.array([len(t)*0.019 for t in text[xs<0]])

busiest_airports.options(
    edge_color_index='SourceID', label_index='City', color_index='AirportID',
    width=800, height=800, finalize_hooks=[rotate_label], cmap='Category20',
    edge_cmap='Category20'
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. The `0.019` in the last line of the function can be changed to adjust the distance between nodes and text labels on the left semicircle of the diagram, which might be good to know if the font size or font type changes.

Comment: Just to be clear, the code requires bokeh as plotting library backend with `hv.extension("bokeh")`.